# Having issues with WebDriverAgent - Appium / Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, selenium, webdriver, appium

I believe I have messed up `WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj` in an attempt to launch my app on a device for testing... is there any way to start over, i.e. delete all corresponding files and then reinstall? I do not seem to be able to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Will deleting the files at Users/isaac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-eoyoecqmiqfeodgstkwbxkfyagll work?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to uninstall and install appium.

`npm uninstall -g appium` and
`npm install -g appium`

Then open WDA xcode project and reconfigure them all.